# Will Firebase docrefs be shared if requested from disparate parts of an application?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, ngrx

I am considering whether I need to store my firebase `DocumentReferences` in my ngrx store. I'd prefer to not have the request duplicate network requests, but I'd also like to avoid the complexity of storing and retrieving DocRefs from the store.

My assumption would be that [@angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) would keep a reference to these DocumentRefs somewhere behind the scenes - like a rxjs `shareReplay()` - but I have not read anything about it. That being said, there is mention of it being:

> ngrx friendly - Integrate with ngrx using AngularFire's action based APIs. [LINK](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#what-is-angularfire)

There is a [fireship tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ngrx-with-angularfire-version-5-firestore/) for putting docs in the store, but I'm not sure if it is even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what you're asking here, but it sounds like your concern is when two parts of your application are listening to the same location in the database, via two different reference objects.  This is not a problem.  The SDK will not duplicate the data sent across the connection for each different reference object, if they point to the same location.  You can be sure that bandwidth use will be minimized to only what's necessary to satisfy all the references being listened to at any given moment.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Do you know where I can read about that? I have not seen that described in the docs.

Comment: It's not documented, it's just kind of an expected optimization.  It was the same way with Realtime Database (many of the same people working on both products).